# CSS display:table for filling height. Different in Chrome/Safari vs Firefox/Opera

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

Using the `display:table` and `display:table-row` CSS attributes, I want my content to fill the remaining available height of a div. In case the content exceeds the available height, I want a scrollbar to be shown.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3HYJx/2/

The behaviour as shown in Google Chrome and Safari is the one I'm trying to achieve. However, Firefox and Opera show it differently. Haven't tried IE yet, but fearing the worst.

Why is this behaviour so different? And even better: how can I achieve what I want (as shown in Chrome) in every browser?

Thanks a lot in advance.

---

Chrome and Safari:
[image: Chrome/Safari sample]

Firefox and Opera:
[image: Firefox/Opera sample]

Comment: I don't see the need for `display: table`/`table-row` in your example. Why not just use `div` and the `overflow` property?

Comment: ExP: thanks for looking into my question. The reason why I can't do that, is because the size of the "title" component is not set. That's why setting the "content" div to `position:absolute` with a certain `top`-offset won't work neither. After a bit of research, the `display:table` did the trick, except for it only being working in Webkit-based browsers.

Comment: Can't crack this one, I'm sure there's an answer and I hope to find out what it is.

Comment: I mean, you could always solve it using jQuery, but that's just not as elegant.

Comment: Does it bother you that the overall height of `#wrapper` is also different in both pictures?

Comment: @thgaskell, I think that's the issue.

Comment: @Godwin I just realized the jsfiddle renders completely differently in Firefox (Mac) than the picture describes. Doesn't even have scroll, the height just expands :/ I can't tell if the problem is the height or the scroll because there's no scrollbar in the 2nd picture so I'm assuming it's overflow is hidden.

Comment: @thgaskell That's the behaviour of Firefox indeed: instead of expanding, I want the height of `#wrapper` to be fixed, allow `#date` and `#title` to take up as many space as needed (although in practice only `#title` can be multiple lines) and fill the rest of the `#wrapper` div with (scrolled) `#content`.
@Godwin Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the table display properties, you could overcome the firefox problem by wrapping two more elements around the text of the scrolling section, so you have three:

- the outer one is a `table-row` container that fills the rest of the table
- inside which we have a **relatively** positioned container with `height` and `width` set to `100%`, and with set vertical scrolling `overflow-y:scroll;`
- the innermost container is **absolutely** with `height` and `width` also set to `100%`

So here I just quickly added two div containers around your content paragraph (you could probably found a more appropriate set of containers according to your needs, but this will do for the illustration):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h2 id="date">Date</h2>
    <h1 id="title">A title ...</h1>
    <div id="contentbox-outer">
        <div id="contentbox-inner">
            <p id="content">The content ...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your whole CSS has to be modified. Your original selectors, with slight modifications:

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    background-color:black;
    padding:10px;
    width: 250px;
    height:350px;
    border-spacing:20px;
}

#date {
    display: table-row;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color:yellow;
}

#title {
    display: table-row;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height:90%;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

note that the `table-row` and `table` elements take now speciffinc styling for tables, like the `border-spacing` property that sets spacing between the table rows, and this you can now combine with the padding property of the table for the appearance you want.

And the styling for the added containers would be something like this (first is still based on your styling, the last two are the additional - inner ones):

```
#contentbox-outer {
    display: table-row;
    font-size: 12pt;
    width: 100%;
    height:90% !important;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color:red;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#contentbox-inner {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%
}
```

I also updated your fiddle for a quick check:
http://jsfiddle.net/3HYJx/7/

**Edit:** This works in browsers like Firefox, Chrome, Safari, but for example not in Opera cause `height: 100%` does not get rendered in documents in strict mode. So with a little more research I found out that you can get it to work in **quirks mode**, here is a **[test html](http://newtpond.com/quirksmode.html)** - the above code but in a quirks mode document. Thanks for giving me a reason to learn that, it's good to know =)

Comment: This seems to be working in both Chrome and Firefox, thanks a lot. Opera still doesn't seem to get it though.

Comment: Also works in Safari, I can think a little more what could work for Opera.

Comment: After looking a around a little I found this article [http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2006/05/cells-with-100-height-in-html-tables] saying that in Opera in tables `hight:100%` does not render right in strict mode but in quirks mode works like a charm. Adding it to the answer.

Comment: Great, that does work! Thank you very much for looking into it and taking the time to respond to my additional question!

Answer (score 1):

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3HYJx/3/

The problem is `height:90% !important;` you have set on `#content`.

You have fixed heights set on `#wrapper`, `#date` and `#title`.

If you set a fixed height on `#content` (since you have everything else with fixed height, so this won't be a problem) you will get the expected result in FireFox too.

Comment: I don't think this solves @Aegonis' problem. What I understand is that the fixed height on `#title` is incorrect, you should assume a fluid height, which means that `#content` should also have a fluid height to fill up the remaining vertical space.

Comment: What @Godwin said indeed. Setting a fixed height on `#title` allows `#wrapper` to expand as `#title` gets larger.